Proxy can't access backend cloud run service when ingress set to internal
I am trying to figure out how I can have all requests have to go through the ESPv2 cloud run container URL so that nobody can make requests to the backend service directly. I thought this could be achieved via IAM roles but now I'm wondering if I need to do something else.
I am running into an issue where the ESPv2 cloud run proxy isn't proxying the request to the backend cloud run service when the backend service ingress control is set to "internal".
When I set the ingress control to "all" I am able to hit the public API endpoints via the ESPv2 cloud run URL meaning the requests are getting proxied successfully.
The service account (default compute one) that the cloud run service uses does have the "Cloud Run Invoker" role set.
Update 1:
To provide more context, I am using the load balancer integration with Cloud Run and have my web app cloud run service on path /* and the ESPv2 public backend cloud run service on path /api/*. I want to keep using ESPv2 because we are using Firebase and can authenticate users out of the box by specifying the security definitions in the open api YAML. Whats not clear to me is how I can add the internal backend service to the load balancer integration. I do see the ingress option internal + load balancer but setting that makes it unreachable through ESPv2.
Update 2:
Diagram

Any help is greatly appreciated!

You pattern makes sense and you have several way to achieve it.
To answer directly to your issue, you set your other Cloud Run service with ingress="internal". This option only allow traffic coming from Internal to reach your Cloud Run services. Traffic coming from

your VPC
a shared VPC
a VPC SC
an internal load balancer

Therefore, the traffic must come from one of these source. The solution is to route the ESPv2 Cloud Run egress traffic (the proxied traffic) to your VPC. To achieve this, you can use the serverless VPC connector or the direct VPC egress feature. I prefer the latest solution (less expensive, easiest to deploy but can consume of lot of IP in your VPC)
In both cases, route ALL the egress traffic through the VPC connector

Now, if you want a proxied connectivity, you can directly use a Global HTTPS load balancer to replace your cloud run ESPv2. And set all the other services with ingress="internal & google load balancing".

The previous option is great, but the Cloud Run URL is still visible from the internet and you could received request on it. Of course, because the request won't come from Load Balancer or from internal, they will be rejected, but maybe you do not want this
That's why, soon and still with a load balancer, you will be able to deactivate the run.app default URL and make your service really hidden from the Internet, and only reachable through a load balancer.

Update 1
According to your comment, I understand the usefulness of ESPv2. So, let's continue with this option.
ESPv2 is a proxy. It terminates the inbound connection and open an outbound one. Therefore, you have to focus on the outbound part, the egress, that reach your other services. And track by which route the requests go through
Many options

Direct access to services: in that case, as explain above, use a serverless VPC connector, or a direct VPC egress to plug the egress traffic of the ESPv2 to your VPC. Very important, route ALL the traffic to the VPC (not only the internal one). This option is compliant with ingress=[internal|load balancing|all] on your services
Use a global HTTPS load balancer: in that case you can create backend service with your Cloud Run services and add them to a Global HTTPS Load Balancer. This option is compliant with ingress=[load balancing|all] -> here the internal ingress is impossible. However, anyone with the correct credential and the correct URL can reach your Global Load Balancer and invoke your CLoud Run services (without using the ESPv2 option)
Use an internal HTTPS Load Balancer: in that case, as before, you have to create backend services with your Cloud Run services. But, this time, you can attach the backend to an internal load balancer, i.e. a load balancer only reachable from your VPC. Because of this, you also have to use a serverless VPC connector or a direct VPC egress, with the egress option set to ALL to route the ESPv2 egress traffic to your VPC to be able to reach your internal load balancer. This option is compliant with ingress=[internal|load balancing|all] on your services.

As you see, identifying the next hop between your ESPv2 and the endpoints is important to set up the correct services/features.

Hi and thank you for your response. To provide more context, I am using the load balancer integration with Cloud Run and have my web app cloud run service on path /* and theESPv2 public backend cloud run service on path /api/*. I want to keep using ESPv2 because we are using Firebase and can authenticate users out of the box by specifying the security definitions in the open api YAML. Whats not clear to me is how I can add the internal backend service to the load balancer integration. I do see the ingress option internal + load balancer but setting that makes it unreachable through ESPv2.

Look at my edit. If it's still not clear, can you share a diagram of what you want to achieve, with the load balancer and other component that you would like to set up.

I've added my diagram of what my current setup looks like. I've had a read of the direct vpc egress and that seems to be what I want. I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCRA7HnZf0g, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJcQBJeMXqA&t=78s but when doing so i am getting a gateway timeout when i make a proxied request via the backend-espv2 proxy

The setup I have now is similar to what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951166/gcp-access-from-api-gateway-to-google-cloud-run-backend?rq=3
If a threat actor spams the public cloud run URL but it is unauthenticated, am I charged for those requests? When I test this out I can see the 403s in the logs of backend cloud run service.

You are not  charged for the request not reaching your service (I mean the 403 is generated by the Google infrastructure and not your service which returns this value)
